# AngularJS on Rails, make a Post request to another website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using AngularJS on Rails in order to make a POST request to another webiste for authenticatng users' login. However, I received CORS error and got a 405 error.

What will be the best way to send a POST request on login in Rails?

Comment: And you are positive that this site allows `POST`s?

Comment: @Borsunho the API document says "POST /api/user/token", so I believe it accepts POST method.

Comment: @BradWerth Even I tried `$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];` It still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening as a security reason because your browser doesn't allow you to send ajax call on other domain.

But however you can achieve that using **jsonp**. You haven't provided your code sample so i can't say exactly but following should solve your problem :

```
//add ?callback=jsonp_callback after your url
// e.g my url is www.xyz.com/abc then
var url = "www.xyz.com/abc?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //success
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //error
    });
```

Comment: is it working ? @Yumiko